# Reload content of DIV using XML as source

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml, xslt

I'm trying to create a news style marquee at the bottom of my XSL page that shows some information it retrieves from an XML file. What I want it to do is automatically refresh the content of only this marquee without the meta refresh of the whole page.

XML example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="news.xsl"?>
<PAGE>
    <MARQUEE>This is the value to refresh</MARQUEE>
</PAGE>
```

XSLT example:

```
<div class="marquee" id="marquee">
<xsl:value-of select="/PAGE/MARQUEE" />
</div>
```

I would prefer a solution using Javascript/JQuery if possible.

Many thanks

Comment: This is really more a javascript/jquery question, than an XSLT one, as before you start writing XSLT you need to know what output you want (i.e what javascript you expect). You will probably find that once you know the JS, the XSLT will be straight-forward. There are probably lots of javascript marquee solutions out there (and questions asking for recommendations of software are generally off-topic on SO), but a quick search on Google throws up this one: https://plugins.jquery.com/marquee/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Ajax to load content dynamically, without the need to refresh the whole page.

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "url.xml",
  dataType: "xml",
  success: function(xml) {
    var data = xml.getElementsByTagNam('MARQUEE')[0].innerText
    $('#marquee')   //... fill the marquee element with the data from the xml
  }
});
```

You can execute it on setInterval or on a refresh button click.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please add some explanation to your code: why does it works? What should it do?